# Why can't I pass props from parent to child. (React / TypeScript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new to TypeScript.
I want to pass props from parent to child.
The type of props is an error..
There is no problem with any type.
I don't know how to write the correct type.

> Property'user' does not exist on type'UserType'.

type.tsx

```
export type UserType = {
    name: string
    image: string
    email: string
    phone: string
    company: {
      name: string
    },
    website: string
  }
```

App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { UserType } from './type';
import { ChildrenComponent } from './ChildrenComponent';

const user:UserType = {
  name: "samplename",
  image: "https://source.unsplash.com/gKXKBY-C-Dk",
  email: "12345@example.com",
  phone: "090-1111-1111",
  company: {
    name: "sampleCompany"
  },
  website: "Goooo.com"
}

export const App:React.FC = () => {
  
  return (
    <div>
      <ChildrenComponent user={user} /> //user type err
    </div>
  )
}
```

ChildrenComponent.tsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { UserType } from './type';

export const ChildrenComponent:React.FC<UserType> = (props) => {
  const { user } = props; //user type err
  return (
    <div>
      <img src={user.image} alt={user.name} />
      <p>{user.name}</p>
      <dl>
        <dt>email</dt>
        <dd>{user.email}</dd>
        <dt>tel</dt>
        <dd>{user.phone}</dd>
        <dt>compony</dt>
        <dd>{user.company.name}</dd>
        <dt>Web</dt>
        <dd>{user.website}</dd>
      </dl>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
React.FC<UserType>
```

This means that the component expects individual props for each of the properties in UserType. So a `name` prop, an `image` prop, an `email` prop, etc. If you want a single `user` prop, then instead do:

```
React.FC<{ user: UserType }>
```

Comment: > individual props for each of the properties ... 
ah I see.Thank you very much.solved.